# Get data from Pandas multiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, uproot

I am using *pandas* and *uproot* to read data from a .root file, and I get a table like the following one:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ySiy.png)

So, from my .root file I have got some branches of a tree.

```
fname = 'ZZ4lAnalysis_VBFH.root' 
key = 'ZZTree/candTree'
ttree = uproot.open(fname)[key]
branches = ['nCleanedJets', 'JetPt', 'JetMass', 'JetPhi'] 
df = ttree.pandas.df(branches, entrystop=40306)
```

Essentially, I have to retrieve "JetPhi" data for each entry in which there are more than 2 subentries (or equivalently, entries for which "nCleanedJets" is equal or greater than 2), calculating the difference of "JetPhi" between the first two subentries and then make a histogram for such differences.

I have tried to look up in the internet and tried different possibilities but I have not found any useful solution.
If someone could give me any hint, advice and/or suggestion, I would be very grateful.
I used to code in C++ and I am new to python.

I used to code in C++, so I am new to python and I do not still master this language.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Pandas with

```py
df[df["nCleanedJets"] >= 2]
```

because you have a column with the number of entries. The `df["nCleanedJets"] >= 2` expression returns a `Series` of booleans (`True` if a row passes, `False` if a row doesn't pass) and passing a `Series` or NumPy array as a slice in square brackets masks by that array (returning rows for which the boolean array is `True`).

You could also do this in Awkward Array before converting to Pandas, which would be easier if you didn't have a `"nCleanedJets"` column.

```py
array = ttree.arrays(branches, entrystop=40306)
selected = array[array.counts >= 2]

awkward.topandas(selected, flatten=True)
```

Masking in Awkward Array follows the same principle, but with data structures instead of flat `Series` or NumPy arrays (each element of `array` is a list of records with `"nCleanedJets"`, `"JetPt"`, `"JetPhi"`, `"JetMass"` fields, and `counts` is the length of each list).

`awkward.topandas` with `flatten=True` is equivalent to what uproot does when `outputtype=pandas.DataFrame` and `flatten=True` (defaults for `ttree.pandas.df`).